# bash lsof : get pid from one tty to another one

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, pid

How to get the pid in tty1 of the process launched in tty2 ?

Context :
Trying to write a bash one-liner to kill a process generating a file when this file exceeds a pre defined max size. (The one-liner is not operating yet as it is as need to embed this into a loop).

During testing, the point is that *lsof* does not return any PID in the terminal tty1 despite the pid exists in the tty2 where the command is run.

tty1: generating the file and monitoring changes

```
MAX_SIZE_Ko=10001;file=test_lsof;dd if=/dev/zero of=$file bs=1k count=800;inotifywait $file;SIZE_Ko=$(du -s $file | cut -f1); [[ "$SIZE_Ko" -gt "$MAX_SIZE" ]] && ( PID=$(lsof $file | tail -n1 | awk -F" " '{ print $2 }') ; [[ ! -z $PID ]] && kill -9 $PID || echo "no running PID modifying $file" )
```

tty2 : increasing the file size

```
for (( 1; 1; 1));do echo -e "foobar\n" >> test_lsof; echo $(( i++ ))" - pid="$$; done
```

Comment: Do you have control over the tty2 process? If so, I think it would just be so much better for you to save the process PID in a way retrievable by the first process, for example by writing it to `test_lsof.pid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, the file is opened only for a short time, so the odds of your lsof catching it are low.

However, you can change that:

```
exec 5>test_lsof
for (( 1; 1; 1)); do
    echo -e "foobar\n" >&5  
    echo $(( i++ ))" - pid="$$
done
```

This uses advanced shell redirection - the exec line opens a file descriptor, the >&5 redirects output from the command to that file descriptor.

If you do that, the shell will be visible to lsof.

Comment: Sure, that's fully right. Thx, as I could not find this tip in the exec man page as this trick is using advanced redirection. I'll investigate that way. Good idea, thx again for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the process in tty2 opens the file only for a split second to append the string. Unless you run lsof in the same split second, you won't catch it.

One way to deal with this is to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/). The program `inotifywait` allows you to wait until the file is opened and the run `lsof`, e.g. `inotifywait $file; lsof $file`.

Comment: thx for the answer but if you read the ugly tty1 one-liner, inotifywait is already the command I'm using.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I missed that. Try moving the lsof part immediately after the inotifywait.

Comment: and lsof stands also quite straight after inotify.

Comment: There're several calls between inotifywait and lsof. That may be enough, as the file is only open for a very small amount of time.